# Angular5 access shared pipe in a shared component

Tags: angular, angular5

folder structure:

```
src
  app
    post
    shared
      layout
        sidebar.component.ts
        sidebar.component.html
      shared.pipe.ts
      shared.module.ts
```

shared.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule,
    ],
  declarations: [
    TimeAgoPipe,
    ProfileImagePipe,
    RoundPipe,
    ListErrorsComponent,
    HeaderNavComponent,
    FileUploadComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    ShowAuthedDirective
  ],
  exports: [
    TimeAgoPipe,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule,
    ListErrorsComponent,
    RoundPipe,
    TranslateModule,
    NgxCarouselModule,
    HeaderNavComponent,
    FileUploadComponent,
    SidebarComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

sidebar.component.html

```
<li class="active list-title">
                  <a href="#">
                      <i class="pe-7s-graph"></i>
                      <p>{{'Groups'|translate}}</p>
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="pe-7s-user"></i>
                    <p>{{'Join Group'|translate}}</p>
                </a>
               </li>                      
              <li>
```

Currently I'm getting an error like this

> compiler.js:486 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: The pipe
>   'translate' could not be found ("
>
> {{[ERROR ->]'Groups'|translate}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to export only component and providers but not the module, Add TranslateModule under modules and remove Modules from exports and have only inside import module section.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule,
    ],
  declarations: [
    TimeAgoPipe,
    ProfileImagePipe,
    RoundPipe,
    ListErrorsComponent,
    HeaderNavComponent,
    FileUploadComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    ShowAuthedDirective
  ],
  exports: [
    TimeAgoPipe,
    ListErrorsComponent,
    HeaderNavComponent,
    FileUploadComponent,
    SidebarComponent
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.
Moved all the modules to 'imports'. But still the same error.

Comment: you have to import TranslateModule wherever you have submodules

Comment: That is not me. It is not fixed

Comment: could you post your related code for modules and pipe as well

Comment: added TranslateModule  to 'imports' and kept everything as safe fixed my issue..
Thanks